# Increasing the expiry date of automatic certificate rollover in ADFS 2.0

Tags: single-sign-on, adfs2.0, adfs

In a new implementation, we had a requirement to increase the certification duration from the Default one year to a bigger number in ADFS 2.0 . Is there an easy way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [blog](http://blog.kloud.com.au/2013/07/17/ad-fs-and-self-signed-token-signing-certificates-3/) gives us a detailed explanation about Self signed certificates and pro's/cons while using it.

Use the below command (excerpt from the blog) to increase certificate duration to 3 years (1095 days):

```
Set-AdfsProperties -CertificateDuration 1095
```